# problem controlling pan and tilt with gui

Tags: urdf, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am a beginner with ROS and have built an URDF Model for a turtlebot. The turtlebot is equiped with a Pan&Tilt unit consisting of 2 servos, which I can manipulate and display with the provided gui Interface in Rviz.

I also have a launch file to start the servos and manipulate them with the keyboard. But this is not linked to my robot model.

How do I bring this two things together, such that I can control the robot in rviz as well as the corresponding Hardware?

I know this is not much information. Here the RQT Graph after starting all the Nodes.

http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/rosgraphnodes762v4fsyrj.png

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81151/problem-controlling-pan-and-tilt-with-gui/) by [mike.sru](https://answers.ros.org/users/6656/mike.sru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a solution for my problem here:
http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Control_with_Gazebo

---

Originally posted by [mike.sru](https://answers.ros.org/users/6656/mike.sru/) with karma: 16 on 2013-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0